# Save android application in sd card

Tags: android

I have a problem all the applications im creating are getting installed in phones internal memory. and my phones memory is low so im flooded by the low space dialogue every time. can someone help please, thanks in advance

Comment: if you are developing ur own applications then they will be stored in the internal memory only. if you download then we can choose the specified folder and store

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the manifest of your application in the stub where you set the version and version name etc add the following tag android:installLocation="preferExternal".
 You can keep it as auto so that the app can be made movable to phone or sd card.

Comment: How could I move the already installed apps from internal memory to SD card? (Those apps are not mine.)

Comment: check this http://www.bongizmo.com/blog/moving-all-android-apps-to-sdcard-apps2sd-froyo/#Troubleshooting

Comment: Rakshi, thats really nice app, but it cannot move system apps. BTW, thanks for your time.

Comment: Realization after reading the documentation on [manifest-element#install](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install).
3 possible values: "internalOnly", "auto" or "preferExternal". The default (if you didn't add the installLocation-tag) is "internalOnly" (but my common sense expected "auto" to be default)

Answer (score 2):

see this

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html